# Entity is Overriding My Table Name Attribute with a Plural

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, data-annotations

I have a table decorated with an attribute specifying the table name, e.g.

```
[Table("MyTable")]
public class MyTable
```

However, when I try to write to it via

```
 repository.Insert(MyTableEntity);
 repository.Commit();
```

It throws an exception

```
Invalid object name 'dbo.MyTables'
```

Note the 's'. I know that you can disable pluralization in codefirst by overriding OnModelCreating, but if I am hand specifying the table name, shouldn't it honor that?

Comment: did you check in the db how is the table being named?

Comment: The name in the database is MyTable

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: No beyond the mentioned override of OnModelCreating. It's ugly and I don't like it, but I haven't been able to get around it. Seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

If you overload the convention,either by Annotation([Talbe()]) or Fluent API(ToTable()),EF will not use pluralization service.

Comment: It *shouldn't* use it, but that's my problem - it is.